# Union of delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I've started learn delegates and have a question:
I write this code:

```
class DelegateLesson
{
    private delegate string Greeting();

    public void StartLesson()
    {
        // Create delegate:
        Greeting greeting = null;

        // Edit delegate:
        // add to delegate
        greeting += BilboGreeting;
        greeting += GendalfGreeting;

        ToConsole(greeting);
        Console.WriteLine();
        ToConsole(this.BilboGreeting, this.GendalfGreeting);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // remove from delegate
        greeting -= GendalfGreeting;
        ToConsole(greeting);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void ToConsole(Greeting greeting)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(greeting());
    }


    private static void ToConsole(params Greeting[] greetings)
    {
        foreach (Greeting greeting in greetings)
            Console.WriteLine(greeting());
    }

    private string BilboGreeting()
    {
        return "Bilbo: Good morning!";
    }

    private string GendalfGreeting()
    {
        return "Gendalf: Bilbo Baggins!";
    }
}
```

I have got next result:

```
Bilbo: Good morning!

Bilbo: Good morning!
Gendalf: Bilbo Baggins!
```

Why doesn't Gendalf want to talk in first case? :)

When I've rewritten code like this:

```
class DelegateLesson
{
    private delegate void Greeting();

    public void StartLesson()
    {
        // same code...
    }

    private static void ToConsole(Greeting greeting)
    {
        greeting();
    }


    private static void ToConsole(params Greeting[] greetings)
    {
        foreach (Greeting greeting in greetings)
            greeting();
    }

    private void BilboGreeting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bilbo: Good morning!");
    }

    private void GendalfGreeting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Gendalf: Bilbo Baggins!");
    }
}
```

All works fine! How does it works?
When I try to use first case and debug it, I noticed that after second + logs says: 'method = internal error evaluating expression'

Comment: Yes, can u post your comment as answer and I'll approved it)

Comment: The question has already been answered; this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It's worth noting that using the `+=` operator directly on a delegate is very rarely done.  The pattern is usually to create an _Event_ based on the delegate and subscribe to the event using the `+=` operator on the Event.  Delegates are type-safe function pointers, events implement a publish/subscribe mechanism.  Take a look at things like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/distinguish-delegates-events and https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-delegates-and-events-in-c-sharp.html